# Simple Binary Search Program....Please tell me what is wrong in this specific code

Tags: java, search, compiler-errors, binary

Im a beginner.
Here is a binary search code.Its showing array out of bounds error for main method.
please look into the program and kindly tell me my mistake.ill be grateful for ur service.
i have to write all this crap cause i cant post it as its asking for more details.

```
public class BinaryS
{
    int n;

    public BinaryS(int z)
    {
    n=z;

    }

    static int pos;
    static boolean flag=false;
    public void disp()
    {
        int arr[]={0,1,2,3,4};
        int len=arr.length;
        int first=0;
        int last=len;
        int mid=(int)(first+last/2);
        //boolean flag=false;
        while(mid>=0 && mid<=len)
        {
        if(n<arr[mid])
        {
            last=mid;
        }
     if(n>arr[mid])
     {
         first=mid;

        }
        if(n==arr[mid])
        {
            flag=true;
            pos=mid+1;
        }
    }
    if(flag==true){
    System.out.println("the no."+n+"is found at"+pos);
    }
    else{
    System.out.println("the no."+n+"is not found ");
    }
    }
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
         BinaryS obj=new BinaryS(2);
         obj.disp();

     }
}
```

Comment: First thing to fix: the indentation. It's all over the place at the moment. Indent it properly and it'll be a lot easier for us all to read, including yourself. Next, describe the problem more clearly, and what you've done to try to diagnose it. (You say it doesn't compile but that it keeps running, which sounds like a contradiction in terms to me... you need to be very precise about exactly what you're seeing.)

Comment: Compilation errors should be easy to fix.  It tells you the class name and line number at which you've made a mistake.  My advice is to clean up the compilation errors and come back when you have run time issues.

Answer (score 2):

Currently your code does compile, and runs forever - because of this loop:

```
while(mid>=0 && mid<=len)
{
    // Code which doesn't modify mid or len
}
```

Assuming it gets into that loop at all (which it does), the condition is never going to become false - so unless you return or break from within the loop (you don't) or an exception is thrown (it isn't) you're just going to keep going round the loop.

This is where you should:

- Use a debugger to observe what's happening
- Think about what the condition should *actually* be and how you want it to become false
- Adjust your code to either change the condition, or change the loop body so that it modifies `mid` or `len`

Comment: edited it added-- while(mid>=0 && mid<=len||flag==false).still out of bounds error.

Comment: Problem is that you don't understand the binary search algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: @anurag1018: Now would be a good time to learn to use a debugger, to understand what your code is doing.

Comment: Id love to do so.I would be highly grateful if u could tutor me how to use it in eclipse.

Comment: @anurag1018: No, that's not really how SO works. There are *loads* of debugging tutorials on the web - I suggest you search for one.